# Display hashmap key in jstl

Tags: jstl, el

I have tried so many different ways to display this contents of the hashmap based on a key and i would like to be told if im doing it the wrong way please?

```
 session.setAttribute("AvailableLessons", availableLessons.getLessons());
     <c:forEach var="temp" items="${sessionScope.AvailableLessons}">
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <form action="" method="POST">
                                <td>
                                    <c:out value="${temp['description']}"/>
                                </td>
                                <td>
```

Bean code: 
     public class LessonTimetable implements Serializable {

```
private Connection connection = null;
private ResultSet rs = null;
private PreparedStatement st = null;
private Map lessons = new HashMap<String, List<Lesson>>();
private DataSource ds = null;
public Lesson less;

public LessonTimetable() {
    // You don't need to make any changes to the try/catch code below
    try {
        // Obtain our environment naming context
        Context initCtx = new InitialContext();
        Context envCtx = (Context) initCtx.lookup("java:comp/env");
        // Look up our data source
        ds = (DataSource) envCtx.lookup("jdbc/LessonDatabase");//change to LessonDatabase..will also have to setup credentials for my virtualmin server account.
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Exception message is " + e.getMessage());
    }
    try {

        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test", "root", "");
        try {
            if (connection != null) {
                // TODO instantiate and populate the 'lessons' HashMap by selecting the relevant infromation from the database
                List<String> putDescriptions = new ArrayList<String>();
                List<String> putDates = new ArrayList<String>();
                List<String> putStartTime = new ArrayList<String>();
                List<Integer> Level = new ArrayList<Integer>();
                List<String> LessonID = new ArrayList<String>();
                List<String> endTime = new ArrayList<String>();
                String query = String.format("SELECT   description,level,startDateTime,endDateTime,lessonid FROM LESSONS");
                st = connection.prepareStatement(query);
                rs = st.executeQuery();
                connection.setAutoCommit(false);
                st.setFetchSize(0);
                while (rs.next()) {
                    String getDescription = rs.getString("description");
                    int level = rs.getInt("level");
                    Timestamp startDate = rs.getTimestamp("startDateTime");
                    Timestamp endDate = rs.getTimestamp("endDateTime");
                    String LessonId = rs.getString("lessonid");
                    this.less = new Lesson(getDescription, startDate, endDate, level, LessonId);
                    putDescriptions.add(less.description);
                    putStartTime.add(less.startTime);
                    endTime.add(less.endTime);
                    List list = Arrays.asList(less.date.split("2010"));
                    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
                        putDates.add(list.get(i).toString());
                        Level.add(less.level);
                        LessonID.add(less.ID);
                        this.lessons.put("description", putDescriptions);
                        this.lessons.put("StartDate", putDates);
                        this.lessons.put("StartTime", putStartTime);
                        this.lessons.put("EndTime", endTime);
                        this.lessons.put("Level", Level);
                        this.lessons.put("LessonID", LessonID);
```

Comment: What is the HashMap? What is the key? Show us the relevant Java code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, `availableLessons.getLessons()`returns a Map, containing `"description"` as a key.

Your code starts with `session.setAttribute("AvailableLessons", availableLessons.getLessons());`. So the attribute `AvailableLessons`contains a Map.

So, all you need to access the value associated to the key `"description"` in that Map is

```
${AvailableLessons['description']}
```

No need for a loop, just like in Java you would only need

```
 availableLessons.get("description")
```

to access this value, without any need for a loop.

Comment: No. you use `${AvailableLessons['description']}`, as stated in my answer. I just want you to notice how JSTL code and Java code are similar: if you don't need a loop in Java, why would you need one in the JSP EL?

Comment: i assmued i needed the loop to display the key once in each td tag

Comment: this works now, but i want to display one value per td in the it displays : [Snowboarding for dummies, Advanced Carving Techniques, How to not fall off the draglift, Gnarliness Extreeeeeeeme, Parallel turns, How to splint a broken leg with a s, Cross-country techniques, Aerobatics, Intermediate Slalom ]